# Why is this rust method thinking that the lifetime of the value is temporary?

Tags: rust, static, lifetime

New to rust. For the code below the problem is in get_value. I want to return a reference to an existing value in a hashmap but if the value doesn't exist I need to return a reference to `BulkString(None)` which represents a sort of null for `RespType`. The compiler returns an issue with the lifetime saying `v` is temporary even though it shares the lifetime of `'a` with `self`. This is the main issue and I'm not sure why it's occurring.

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::sync::RwLock;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Eq)]
pub enum RespType<'a> {
    SimpleString(&'a str),
    RespError((&'a str, &'a str)),
    Integer(i32),
    BulkString(Option<&'a str>),
    Array(Vec<RespType<'a>>),
}

type Db<'a> = RwLock<HashMap<&'a str, RespType<'a>>>;
pub trait KeyValueStore<'a> {
    fn get_value(&'a self, key: &'a str) -> &'a RespType<'a>;
    fn set_value(&'a mut self, key: &'a str, value: RespType<'a>) -> &'a RespType<'a>;
}

impl<'a> KeyValueStore<'a> for Db<'a> {
    fn get_value(&'a self, key: &'a str) -> &'a RespType<'a> {
        static null_bulk_string:RespType = RespType::BulkString(None);
        match self.read().unwrap().get(key) {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => {
                &null_bulk_string
            }
        }
    }

    fn set_value(&'a mut self, key: &'a str, value: RespType<'a>) -> &'static RespType<'static> {
        static ok: RespType = RespType::SimpleString("OK");
        (*self.get_mut().unwrap()).insert(key, value).unwrap();
        &ok
    }
}

fn main(){

}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a5154490604b06f6e588d3b30bec908f)

Gives the following error:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing temporary value
  --> src/main.rs:23:24
   |
22 |         match self.read().unwrap().get(key) {
   |               -------------------- temporary value created here
23 |             Some(v) => v,
   |                        ^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0515`.
```

I'm also wondering if this is the right way to do it, to have a static value of the type put behind the reference if the actual value doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the reason is that v was gotten while a read lock was acquired. It will go out of scope when the read lock was release.

Suppose rust allows you to return v, it will be a memory problem if someone else removes v from the map later.